# how to compare value of a row in database table to a string in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I am creating an app, that take value of row of particular attribute from database and compare it with string. but null point exception occurred in if condition. Is there is any other way to take value from database and compare it with particular string.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@include file="faaltu.jsp"%>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<body>
<%
String id=request.getParameter("t1");
String pwd=request.getParameter("p1");


DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","kajal");
PreparedStatement st1=con.prepareStatement("select * from kamp where userid=? and password=?");
st1.setString(1,id);
st1.setString(2,pwd);

ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery();

if(rs1.next()==true)
{

String k=(String)session.getAttribute("hey"); //hey is passed from other jsp file. it is an attribute of database table named gender
if(k.equals("female")) //here i get java.lang.NullPointerException 
//here female is string that user will select
{
response.sendRedirect("bhatia.html");
}
else
response.sendRedirect("a1.html");
}
else
{
response.sendRedirect("b.html");
}
con.close();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Means `hey` attribute is not available in `session`.

Comment: And you should compare it like `if(k.equals(rs1.getString("gender")))`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]!. Please read [ask] section for help regarding how to ask!

Answer (score 0):

To check use this:

```
   if("female".equals(rs1.getString("gender")))
```